# Bind a JavaScript array to a Vue 3 component's v-for in template to update DOM

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, vue.js

I've just started learning Vue 3 and I'm trying to create a Vue Component that is bound to a JavaScript array ** (defined and modified outside Vue)** and uses that array to render a `v-for` list of child Vue components.

In the code below, I have my "`layer-container`" Vue component that has a template that renders a list of "`layer-item`" subcomponents using data from a JavaScript array `layersGlobal`. If you run it, you can see that the items are rendered properly from the initial data in the array, but when the array is updated (after 1 second, via a `push()` call in `setInterval()`) the list is not rerendered, and the DOM is not updated.

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="layers">
    <layer-container />
  </div>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
  <script>
    var layersGlobal = [
      {name: "Layer A"},
      {name: "Layer B"}
    ];

    let app = Vue.createApp({
      data: function() {
        return {}
      },
      methods: {}
    });

    app.component("layer-container", {
      template: `
                  <div class="layer-container text-light">
                      <layer-item v-for="layer in layers" v-bind:name="layer.name" v-bind:key="layer.name"></layer-item>
                  </div>
              `,
      components: ["layer-item"],
      data: function() {
        return {
          layers: layersGlobal
        }
      },
    });

    app.component("layer-item", {
      template: `
                  <div class="layer-item">
                      <span>{{ name }}</span>
                  </div>
              `,
      props: ["name"]
    });

    app.mount("#layers");

    setTimeout(() => {
      layersGlobal.push({name: "Layer C"});
      console.log("Layers:", layersGlobal);
    }, 1000);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Am I doing something wrong, or misinterpreting how Vue is reactive with arrays? Is it possible to bind a JavaScript array declared outside Vue to a Vue component like this, or can/should I be doing it another way?

I've looked around for a solution and found some example code that works in Vue 2, but not Vue 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reactive data must be updated within the context of the component. You probably want to call `setTimeout` inside of the component's definition and update the reactive variable `this.layers` instead of the global array.

```js
app.component("layer-container", {
    /* ... */
    data: function () {
        return {
            layers: layersGlobal
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        setTimeout(() => this.layers.push({ name: "Layer C" }), 1000)
    }
})
```

Alternatively, if you need to update the data from outside the component, you need to explicitly define your global array as a **reactive** object, using the `ref()` function.

```
const layersGlobal = Vue.ref([ /* ... */ ])

setTimeout(() => layersGlobal.value.push({ name: "Layer C" }), 1000)
```

Note the `.value` property being used to access the actual object.

Comment: Okay, I guess you're saying that binding an external JavaScript array to the Vue component isn't possible.  But how could I update the array from outside the component?  Like if I have an arbitrary layersGlobal.push({name: "Layer C"}); somewhere in my JavaScript code, how could I update the Vue component's data from outside the component code?

Comment: In that case, you must explicitly define a **reactive** global array. I edited my answer to include more details.

Comment: You're awesome.  Works like a charm.